# Unable to display Team Projects list in Azure DevOps extension

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-devops-extensions

I'm trying to display a projects list using a pick list in an Azure DevOps (TFS) extension. Following is a code snippet I have in the task.json:

Input:

```
{
      "name": "project",
      "type": "pickList",
      "label": "Project",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "required": false,
      "helpMarkDown": "Select the root area.",
      "properties": {
        "DisableManageLink": "True"
      }
    }
```

Source Definition:

```
{
      "target": "project",
      "endpoint": "http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0",
      "selector": "jsonpath:$.name",
      "keySelector": "jsonpath:$.name",
      "authKey": "tfs:teamfoundation"
    }
```

My local environment has TFS 2015, and the URL works fine in the browser.
However, the pick list is not getting filled up in the extension.

Any idea what has gone wrong here?

Btw, I can see a '400 (Bad Request)', when I look at the browser console.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

THIS WORKS!  (even a surprise to me):

```
"inputs": [
        {
            "name": "sourceProject",
            "type": "pickList",
            "label": "Source project",
            "defaultValue": "",
            "required": true,
            "helpMarkDown": "Select the TFS Project.",
            "properties": {
                "EditableOptions": "True"
            }
        }
    ],
    "dataSourceBindings": [
        {
            "target": "sourceProject",
            "endpointId": "tfs:teamfoundation",
            "endpointURL": "{{endpoint.url}}/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0",
            "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$.value[*]",
            "resultTemplate": "{ \"Value\" : \"{{{id}}}\", \"DisplayValue\" : \"{{{name}}}\" }"
        }
    ]
```

[image]
Notice that the "runSelector" and "resultTemplate" are properly defined.  The real key was the correct JSON Path query in "resultSelector" AND the "endpointId", which is using "tfs:teamfoundation" that you had mislabeled.  The resultTemplate is to format the dropdown list.

I created a GitHub repo with a working extension that I was able to test on my own TFS collection.
https://github.com/Antebios/vsts-projectlist-task

Edit:  This works for Azure Devops, but throws an error for TFS 2015 that I'm using.  It looks like the `"endpointId": "tfs:teamfoundation"` might be invalid for TFS.